# Linq query returns right number of results, all but the first are null

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, entity-framework-5

I am trying to get a list of `User` using the lookup table `ProjectFollower`. This is the query I am using. It returns a list of 4 items. The first item in the list has a value, the next three are null. There are in fact 4 results in the database. Why are all but the first null?

```
 subscribers = project.ProjectFollower.Select(u => u.User).ToList();
```

**UPDATED** for Clarity.

The ProjectFollower table has 4 entries for this project, with 4 different UserIDs and the same ProjectID. Those 4 UserIDs correspond to existing Users.

Comment: Check in the db once again? Are you sure comparing the right databases?

Comment: Are you sure all your `ProjectFollower` entries *have* users associated with them?

Comment: Jon, that was the problem, my project variable didn't "Include" the Users in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Jon's comment. The problem was with the query.

I had

```
                var project = db.Projects
                    .Include(i => i.ProjectFollower)
                    .Include(i => i.User)
                    .SingleOrDefault(i => i.ProjectID == project_id);
```

I changed it to

```
                var project = db.Projects
                    .Include(i => i.ProjectFollower)
                    .Include(i => i.ProjectFollower.Select(v => v.User))
                    .Include(i => i.User)
                    .SingleOrDefault(i => i.ProjectID == project_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
subscribers = project.ProjectFollower
.Where(u => u.User != null)
.Select(u => u.User).ToList();
```

Comment: that will probably only give him the one user still

Comment: Yes, but the list won't be 4 elements long.

Comment: I would try not calling ToList(). 'IQueryable<User> subscribers = project.ProjectFollower.Select(u => u.User);' IQueryable uses lazy evaluation and will populate values only when you iterate over the collection. Calling ToList() forces immediate evaluation and that may be the problem here... it's only populating the value of the first element in the collection.